# 'suffuse': How can you pour something (from) below?

Tags: etymology

I already understand so ask NOT about definitions, below which I instead purpose to burrow.
I heed the Etymological Fallacy.

> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/suffuse): Late 16th century: from Latin *suffus-* 'poured into', from *sub-* **'below, from below'** + *fundere* **'pour'**.
>
> [Etymonline entry for '**suffusion**', to which the entry for 'suffuse' simply links](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=suffuse&searchmode=none): late 14c., from Latin *suffusionem* (nominative *suffusio*) "a pouring over," noun of action from past participle stem of *suffundere* "pour upon, overspread, suffuse," from *sub* **"under"** (see [sub-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sub-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + *fundere* **"to pour"** (see [found](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=found&allowed_in_frame=0) (v.2)).

Comment: What If I have an upside down cup of helium and I tip it, the helium will pour "up" right?

Comment: Not in a vacuum it won't.

Comment: Did I say it was in a vacuum?

Comment: I assumed you did, but I couldn't hear you because you were in a vacuum.

Comment: Do you impose too strict a logic on the attachment of meaning to verbal expressions? If you pour water into a sponge, the water will spread out under the exterior surface. The average human mind seems to enjoy *free association* without the excessive interference of logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the origin. The intended meaning of the prefix *sub-* in this case is not ***from* below**; it is **below**. For *suffuse*, it changes the subject of the verb from the *thing that does the pouring* to the *thing into which the pouring takes place*. Here, *below* is used as a literal description, but also as an analogy.

> Literal:
>
> > When you pour something from a jug to a cup, the cup is physically *below* the jug.
>
> Analogy:
>
> > One who receives work from another is metaphorically *below* the person providing the work. *—the thing being poured is the work.*

Something is *suffused* from something that *diffuses*.

Comment: I was typing something to this effect and saw your answer. I would only add that a use of 'suffuse' as a verb meaning to pour up from, brings to mind leaky basements and hot springs, where water may literally appear to be poured up and out of the ground.

Comment: The directionality of the pour is not actually specified by the usage of *suffuse*, so it is important to not confuse the issue. If your basement walls had leaks instead of the floor, the room would still be described as *suffused with water*.

Comment: This is an interesting theory. Are you aware of any definitive corroboration?

Comment: I was unable to find any acceptable etymology definition for this word when I was constructing my answer. I deduced this information based on the etymologies and meanings of similar words.